# Tor website as proxy like receiving server

Tags: tor, sniffing

I want to create a anonymous application that will send data all the time to my server. I don't want my ip to be exposed so I wanted to use Tor. I wanted to send sniffed packets to this server and analyze it here. To sniff and send data I'm using command `dumpcap -w - | nc ip port`. Can I somehow use Tor server (Raspberry PI) as a receiver so I dont need to hard-code my ip address in my program and use .onion server instead?

Comment: Are you basically asking how to use Tor for NAT holepunching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seem to need is called [Tor hidden service](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-onion-service.html.en). This could be any service based on TCP protocol, including HTTP, rsync, or even *nc* as in your example. You set up the  service to listen on localhost:port on your receiver, configure your Tor client (running on the same receiver) to forward the incoming connections to your localhost:port, and use Tor client on your sender to connect to the hidden service.